# How to get a lot of if statements more readable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently practiced python and I was finding myself get involved with a lot of if statements for a simple rock paper scissors game it looks like this: 
and my question is how i get my code more efficient and more friendly to write and read

```
 while True:

        player_choice = raw_input("\n1-Rock\n2-Paper\n3-Scissors\n{} choose a number:".format(name))
        player_choice = int(player_choice)

        if player_choice == 1:
            player_choice = Choices.rock
        if player_choice == 2:
            player_choice = Choices.paper
        if player_choice == 3:
            player_choice = Choices.scissors


    # Getting the cpu choice.
        cpu_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
        if cpu_choice == 1:
            cpu_choice = Choices.rock
        if cpu_choice == 2:
            cpu_choice = Choices.paper
        if cpu_choice == 3:
            cpu_choice = Choices.scissors


        if player_choice == cpu_choice:
            print"\n Its a Tie!\n!"

        if player_choice == Choices.paper and cpu_choice == Choices.rock:
            print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)

        if player_choice == Choices.scissors and cpu_choice == Choices.paper:
            print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)

        if player_choice == Choices.rock and cpu_choice == Choices.scissors:
            print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)

        if cpu_choice == Choices.scissors and player_choice == Choices.paper:
            print"\n Too bad!\n{} you lost!".format(name)

        if cpu_choice == Choices.paper and player_choice == Choices.rock:
            print"\n Too bad!\n{} you lost!".format(name)

        if cpu_choice == Choices.rock and player_choice == Choices.scissors:
            print"\n Too bad!\n{} you lost!".format(name)*
```

Comment: I think **_readable_** is really more appropriate the efficient in the context of you question. Because without being readable it is efficient especially if you were using `elif`.

Comment: So what's `Choices`, is it a `Enum` subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements can be replaced by *dictionaries*. For example, mapping an integer to a specific `Choices` attribute can be done with a dictionary like this:

```
choices = {1: Choices.rock, 2: Choices.paper, 3: Choices.scissors}
```

Now you can use

```
player_choice = choices[player_choice]
```

and

```
cpu_choice = random.choice(choices.values())
```

From an encapsulation point of view, it should really be the responsibility of the `Choices` object to handle this mapping. If you were to use an actual [`enum.Enum` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) (requires Python 3 or the installation of [the `enum34` backport package](https://pypi.org/project/enum34/)) then you could just use:

```
player_choice = Choices(player_choice)
```

but depending on how you defined `Choices`, you could give it a `__call__` method that basically uses the above mapping to give you the same result.

Next, you could use a dictionary to determine winners:

```
# if a player picks the key, and the opponent has picked the value,
# then the player wins.
wins_against = {
    Choices.rock: Choices.scissors,
    Choices.paper: Choices.rock,
    Choices.scissors: Choices.paper,
}
```

then determine the winner:

```
if player_choice == cpu_choice:
    print"\n Its a Tie!\n!"
elif wins_against[player_choice] == cpu_choice:
    print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)
else:  # not the same, and not a win, so the player lost
    print"\n Too bad!\n{} you lost!".format(name)
```

That mapping could also be part of your `Choices` enumeration objects however; give those a `wins_against` attribute:

```
if player_choice == cpu_choice:
    print"\n Its a Tie!\n!"
elif player_choice.wins_against == cpu_choice:
    print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)
else:
    print"\n Too bad!\n{} you lost!".format(name)
```

If you were to use the `enum` library, the code could become:

```
from enum import Enum

class Choices(Enum):
    rock = 1, 'scissors'
    paper = 2, 'rock'
    scissors = 3, 'paper'

    def __new__(cls, value, win_against):
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        instance._value_ = value
        instance._win_against = win_against
        return instance

    @property
    def win_against(self):
        return type(self)[self._win_against]


 while True:
    options = '\n'.join(['{}-{}'.format(c.value, c.name) for c in choices])
    player_choice = raw_input("\n\n{} choose a number:".format(
        options, name))
    try:
        player_choice = int(player_choice)
        player_choice = Choices(player_choice)
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a valid option, try again"
        continue

    cpu_choice = random.choice(list(Choices))

    if player_choice is cpu_choice:
        print"\n Its a Tie!\n!"
    elif player_choice.wins_against is cpu_choice:
        print"\n Congratulations!\n{} you won!".format(name)
    else:  # not the same, and not a win, so the player lost
        print"\n Too bad!\n{} you lost!".format(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use if/elif/else statements - it will only compare the conditionals until a true value occurs.
And you may want to put an error message if the user inputs some other value

```
    if player_choice == 1:
        player_choice = Choices.rock
    elif player_choice == 2:
        player_choice = Choices.paper
    elif player_choice == 3:
        player_choice = Choices.scissors
    else:
        print "Invalid choice"
```

Comment: Better than the code from the question, but far from perfect.